# How do I trigger function in sibling component without using contextAPI or Redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

How do I trigger a function in table-component from form-component without using Redux, contextAPI etc..

Parent:

```
...

  <Form />
  <Table />
```

Table component:

```
function TableComponent() {
..
...
 const updateTable = () => {
  //do some state here
  //should be triggered by sibling component/form component
 }
 
}
```

Form component:

```
function FormComponent() {
..
...

 const submitForm = () => {
   ...
   *trigger the updateTable() from table component here*
 }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution here is to ["lift state up,"](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) or move the state to the common parent component. In your case, it might look something like moving the form state and the submit form function up to the parent, and then passing the always up-to-date table data down to the Table component:

```
function Parent() {
  const [formState, setFormState] = React.useState(/*...*/);
  const [tableState, setTableState] = React.useState(/*...*/);

  const submitForm = (data) => {
    /* ... */
    // update the table data here
  }

  return (
    <Form handleSubmit={submitForm} />
    <Table data={tableData} />
  );
}
```

This way, your Table component only cares about displaying the data you pass to it via props and the Parent component takes care of managing the state received from the form.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you have to have a state at parent component and pass it to table-component. And you can pass function to form-component from parent component which update the state.
In table component, you can have this passed state as dependancy in dependancy array which is calling the desire function(updateTable).

Example:

Parent Component:

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
   const [loadTableData, setLoadTableData] = useState(false);

   return (
     <>
         <TableComponent loadTableData={loadTableData} />
         <FormComponent setLoadTableState={setLoadTableData} />
     </>
   )
}
```

TableComponent:

```
const TableComponent = ({loadTableData}) => {
   useEffect(() => {
      if(loadTableData){
         updateTable();
      }
   }, [loadTableData]);

    //other body
}
```

FormComponent:

```
const FormCompondent = ({setLoadTableData}) => {
   const loadTableData = () => {
     setLoadTableData(true)
   }

// other body
}
```